# Bootstrapping data for Google App Engine local database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

Is there a way to programmatically add entities to the GAE database? I'm wondering if there is something that parallels Django's [fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/). Everything that I have found so far indicates you can only do it by a custom url handler which seems inelegant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can programmatically add entities as explained in the documentation ([Creating, Retrieving, Updating, and Deleting Entities](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities)):

```
sandy = Account(username='Sandy', userid=123, email='sandy@example.com')
sandy_key = sandy.put()
```

You could implement your own fixtures by hard-coding all the data or reading it from a text file (as part of the deployment).

Comment: How do you run it within the correct environment to create the entities in the local database?

Comment: You'll have to use a custom url handler, but that's not as bad as it seems.  It's just like an AWS lambda function or a REST API, and that's about as elegant as any web service these days.  You can call it directly from your web browser, how cool is that?